# LinkedList<T> as IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>>

Tags: c#, linq, linked-list, ienumerable

I need to find an element in linked list by a certain criteria, and Linq is an excellent way to do that — except that afterwards I need to use this element not only as `T`, but as `LinkedListNode<T>`, traversing through the rest of the list starting from this node using `.Next`. Is there a way to treat LinkedList that I have not as `IEnumerable<T>`, but as `IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>>`?

Comment: call .ToList() on your collection

Comment: Are you very sure you need a `LinkedList<>` ? Most questions about it here are solved by simply using `List<>`.

Comment: @ssg Oh...that exists...

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a duplicate. Sorry, should've google better.